# GitHub folder not accessible

Tags: git, github

I have a folder in GitHub that is not accessible. I accidentally initialised git in the wrong directory, so then deleted the local git file. I have re-committed but the folder named "static" is still not accessible.

Here is a picture illustrating the issue:

[image: GitHub folders]

Comment: you're referring to "static" in that picture?  Do you have a .gitmodules file?

Comment: @rogerdpack yes

Comment: @rogerdpack I deleted this from the local directory

Comment: github link please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your picture, the static folder is simply a gitlink (a SHA1 reference).
It is not a submodule (or it would be listed in the `.gitmodules` file)

Do a **`git rm --cached static`** (no trailing '`/`') to remove that entry.
Then a `git add .` should be able to pick up the `static/` folder content.
Check that with a `git status`, then commit and push.